# Express route in firebase responds 500 error for post request with JSON body

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, axios, google-cloud-functions

I was trying create a **react project with firebase as backend**(firebase functions + **express**). I am using a **post** route which is expected to **receive a json as request body** and respond with 200 status once the data is inserted into firestore I am use axios to send the post request along with that, the rote responds with a **500 error in postman** request and **working fine with a simple html form.**

code for route (Express + firebase functions)

```
/*imports*/
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

var app = express();

app.use(jsonParser);

/*route*/
app.post('/create',jsonParser,(request, response)=>{
    (async ()=>{
        try{
            var data = {
                fullName : request.body.name,
                email : request.body.email
            };
            await db.collection('signup').doc("/"+request.body.email+"/").create(data);
            return response.status(200).json(data);
        }catch(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
            console.log("name on body"+request.body.name);
            return response.status(500).send("data"+request.body.name);
        }
    })(); 
});
```

and this is how I post data from front end

```
await axios.post(API_BASE_URL+endpoint,body,config).then(function(response){
    return response;
}).catch(function(error){
      throw error;
});
```

following is what I tried to post as body

```
 let data = {
   fullName: "John Doe",
   email: "john@examplemail.com",
 };
```

Comment: What does the functions error log say?

Comment: `doc().create()` is not a method. Did you mean `doc().set()`? [See docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference). Also, I don't see `admin.initializeApp()` in there which you would also need.

Comment: All those stuff are there there are some get routes they make the code so long thats why I hide it

Comment: Could you also share the Stackdriver error return from Cloud Functions?

Comment: Michael Bleigh thank you that was the exact problem once I used set() it worked. thank you all.